# Custom index for Tradingview Pine-script indicator - Trouble defining security

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script and have not found a script for what I would think would be basic - custom index. I plan on using the script to create a customer index of stocks. For the code below

```
  //@version=5
   indicator("Oil_Majors_Index")

   BP_close=security(symbol="NYSE:BP”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close) 

    //COP_close=Security(Symbol=“NYSE:COP”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close)
   //CVX_close=Security(Symbol=“NYSE:CVX”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close)
   //XOM_close=Security(Symbol=“NYSE:XOM”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close)
  //OIL_Majors_Close=(BP_close+COP_close+CVX_close+XOM_close)/4
```

plot(BP_close)

I am getting this error message

```
 Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 6: mismatched character '\n' expecting '"'
```

The code seems so simple so I do not understand what I could be doing wrong. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Several issues with your script.

- The closing quote on `symbol` should be `"` but you're using `”`.
- Wrong indentation. Pine is indentation-sensitive.
- `Resolution` should be a simple string. If you want the current timeframe of the chart, you should use an empty string.

This will work.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Oil_Majors_Index")

BP_close = request.security("NYSE:BP", "", close) 

//COP_close=Security(Symbol=“NYSE:COP”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close)
//CVX_close=Security(Symbol=“NYSE:CVX”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close)
//XOM_close=Security(Symbol=“NYSE:XOM”, resolution=timeframe.period, expression=close)
//OIL_Majors_Close=(BP_close+COP_close+CVX_close+XOM_close)/4
plot(BP_close)
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Not sure I would have determined the difference between  " and ”